# Corrupt `reverse i-search` database: why and how?

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems, corruption

I made a recording of this as it's never happened to me before and seemed pretty weird:

https://asciinema.org/a/qVSUzkIX2wLia7EzCFhCYHb9Q

1. Under which conditions would the bash completion database become corrupted?
2. Where do the files live so I can wipe them?
3. Should I be thinking about a new HDD right about now?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of thing usually happens because the *terminal* has been corrupted in some way, often by `cat`ting a binary file. Have you tried a `reset`?

If it really is the Bash history that is broken that is stored in `~/.bash_history`.

Comment: That looks to be the case, thankyou for the info! Since reporting this I have had a server reboot and the issue seems to have resolved itself. Interestingly, prior to reboot it did persist between terminal sessions- not sure how to explain that... but I have a lot of things loaded in my profile on there so really, it could be a vast number of things :p